# calculating number of bounces with postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the number of organic bounces with postgresql. I want to count all the instances where a user came to site.com and them leaves after viewing the first page (e.g. row 4,5 and 6 for user ID 1. In contrast to row numbers 1-3 where user ID 1 came in from google and visited 2 more site.com pages.)

The correct answer would be user ID 1 bounced 3 times and user ID 2 didn't bounce at all. I believe row_number() and partition by might be used to solve this problem. Any help building a postgressql query would be appreciated.

EDIT- here is a link to a jfiddle with schema and data [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/39067](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08eee).

Comment: Why do you post plain ascii text as an image. This makes it **really** hard to construct a test case of your sample data. An example on http://sqlfiddle.com would be the best thing to do.

Comment: Here is the fiddle with Postgres: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/39067 Btw: with Postgres there is no need to store that `row_number` you can generate that on the fly based on the `datetime` column.

Comment: why not 1, 4, 5, 6 ? after 1 row number he leaves the site....

Comment: Row number 1,2,3 are a group. user ID 1 came in from google and then visited two more pages in the site(row number 2 and 3). For row number 4,5,6 user ID 1 came from google left, came back in from bing.com and then left and came to the site from ask.com. user ID 1 for row number 4,5,6 looked at one page and then left and came back in through a search engine.

Comment: It's impossible to know when the site is visited from google.com or other search site. So question, Do you have a list of search sites? when if there a list of search sites it's possible to find if webpage was visited from search site or not and give you correct results.

Comment: Yes. The 4 search sites I care about are google,yahoo, bing and ask.com.

Comment: Still not clear what you're trying to get from the data. Why has User ID 2 not bounced? Rows 1-3 are identical to 7-9. I've grouped the items by site and then by user. Usually by bounce rate you're referring to people who leave the site i.e. don't go beyond the page they landed on. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08eee/5

Comment: User ID 1 row 1 comes from google.com and goes to site.com/product. He then navigates from site.com/product to site.com/product/1 from within the site.com and then to site.com/product/2.This sequence since he navigated from within the site to another page. user ID 1 then leaves the site.com and searches on google and comes back to the site site.com/product/2 (row 4). He leaves site.com again and searches on bing.com and comes back to site.com/product/10. I want to count the number of times he comes from a search engine (google/bing/ask/yahoo) looks at one page and then leaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question starts about a rate but then it changes to *The correct answer would be user ID 1 bounced 3 times and user ID 2 didn't bounce at all* so I'm answering the correct answer which is a step in the direction of the rate.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cabb3/2)

```
select user_id, count(c = 1 or null)
from (
    select user_id, g, count(*) c
    from (
        select *,
            count(referring_url != 'site.com' or null)
            over (partition by user_id order by datetime) g
        from t
    ) s
    group by user_id, g
) s
group by user_id;
 user_id | count 
---------+-------
       1 |     3
       2 |     0
```

If you want to count only search engines then:

```
count(referring_url in (
    'google.com', 'bing.com', 'ask.com', 'yahoo.com'
    ) or null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.referring_url <> 'site.com'
AND EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM Table1 ex
        WHERE ex.user_id = t1.user_id
        AND ex.referring_url <> 'site.com'
        AND ex.stamp < t1.stamp
        );
```

BTW: I renamed `datetime` to `stamp`, since it is a reserved word.

UPDATE: if you are only interested in the rate, you could do;

```
SELECT t1.user_id, COUNT(*) AS reet
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.referring_url <> 'site.com'
AND EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM Table1 ex
        WHERE ex.user_id = t1.user_id
        AND ex.referring_url <> 'site.com'
        AND ex.stamp < t1.stamp
        )
GROUP BY t1.user_id
        ;
```

UPDATE: if you want the users with zero reeats as well you could use a join on a CTE (or on a subquery):

```
WITH cnt AS (
        SELECT tx.user_id , COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM Table1 tx
        WHERE tx.referring_url <> 'site.com'
        AND EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM Table1 ex
                WHERE ex.user_id = tx.user_id
                AND ex.referring_url <> 'site.com'
                AND ex.stamp < tx.stamp
                )
        GROUP BY tx.user_id
        )
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_id
        , COALESCE(cnt.cnt, 0) AS reet
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN  cnt ON cnt.user_id = t1.user_id
        ;
```